# How to choose a suitable transistor for switching

Tags: transistors

I am building a circuit that involves switching 1000 LEDs via IC drivers. Each IC output has 10 LEDs connected to it, and these are grouped together by their cathodes, in groups of 100, such that only one group is enabled at once.
To acheive this cathode switching, I use another IC output, and want to switch it via a transistor that can sink enough power comfortably. Allowing a maximum of 20mA per LED, I need an NPN transistor that can sink 2 amps of current. My circuit runs at 5 volts.

I'm not sure how to get about searching for an appropriate transistor, with so many available. Does anyone know of a parameterised search engine that would allow this?
I have come across a couple, but they were overly complicated for someone such as myself who has a relatively basic knowledge of electronics.

If there is no such thing, then a suggestion for my particular use case would also be appreciated. This transistor will be switched by an IC that can supply around 10mA.

Comment: What voltage levels are available from the IC that supplies up to 10mA? If you have a good voltage swing you may want to consider an N channel MOSFET as the switch element.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than switching abruptly a 2A current, from a regulated 5V source,
you might use a 5V source that can be logic-controlled.  There's no need for
a separate switch and DC supply, if the DC supply is (as many are) 
controllable.[observe EN input on this IC regulator](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP59300-D.PDF)